# Is this table not allowing the CSS to function properly

Tags: css, wordpress

In my footer here the social media links should be inline with the form.  Is something in the form overwriting the style of the social div?

The style for the form is being generated through mailchimp and I'm not sure if the issue lies there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the form of .footerForm then include this in your style sheet

```
.footerForm{
float:left;
}
```

Then you need to modify the width of the .social class (style.css line 1417) to 100px.

```
.social {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 95px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

This fixes the issues for me in ff

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `width: auto;` on `#site-info, #site-generator` `style.css:1369`

And float the form left.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.social` to:

```
.social {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Instead of

```
.social {
    padding-left: 95px;
}
```